# Factoring out a value to find the convergent series.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, infinite-product

Hey guys was wondering if someone could help me figure out what is happening in this practice problem as I cant determine what they are doing certain steps.
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{6}{9n^2+3n-2}$$
The top is the original problem, after factoring the denominator you get the following
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{6}{(3n-1)(3n+2)}$$
after this the example does the following
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[\frac{6}{9n-3}-\frac{6}{9n+6}\right]=2\sum_{n=1}^ \infty \left[\frac{1}{3n-1}-\frac{1}{3n+2}\right]$$
Now my question is how they went from increasing the denominator by a factor of 3 and removing the 2. I dont understand why and how that was done if someone could please explain this I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Forget the sum symbols and prove the last algebraic equality

Comment: $6=2 \cdot 3$ and divide above and below by $3$.

Comment: Thats the thing though they increased the denominator by a factor of three when separating the fractions

Comment: @CarlosV You are right: $$\frac1{3n-1}-\frac1{3n+2}=\frac3{(3n-1)(3n+2)}$$ I'd say forget the $\;9n-3\;$ and etc. in the previous expression's denominators and just jump from the middle expression to the last one in the right.

Answer (score 3):

This comes from partial fractions decomposition:
$$\frac1{(3n-1)(3n+2)}=\frac13\frac 1{3n-1}-\frac13\frac 1{3n+2}.$$
I don't think it was a good idea to expand the denominators.

*Some details:*

We can decompose  $$\frac1{(3x-1)(3x+2)}=\frac A{3x-1}+\frac B{3x+2}$$
for a unique pair of numbers $(A,B)$. Multiply both sides by $(3x-1)(3x+2)$ to remove denominators. We obtain
$$1=A(3x+2)+B(3x-1)$$
Now set $x=\dfrac13$. This yields $\;1=A\cdot(1+2)+B\cdot 0$, whence $\;A=\dfrac13$.

Similarly, set $x=-\dfrac23$. You get $\;1=A\cdot 0+B(-2-1)$, whence $B=-\dfrac13$.

Comment: That should be $$2\left(\frac 1{3n-1} -\frac 1{3n+2}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you. After reading the book again I realized that it has to be done with partial fractions as you mentioned will attempt the problem again.

Comment: Partial fractions decomposition is a technique to write a fraction, when its denominator is factored as a product of irreducible factors, as a linear combination of fractions with one irreducible factor each. Here, computing the coefficients leads to $\frac13$ and $-\frac13$. I can give some details, if you wish.

Comment: No, the coefficients are 2 and -2.

Comment: @amWhy: I did not take into account the $6$ in the numerators.

Comment: I see; then all is well @Bernard.  I had worked with the factor of 6 in the numerator,

Comment: @Bernard Im still having some problems do you think you would be able to give me a bit more details if possible?

Comment: I'll try my best…

Comment: @Carlos V: I posted details. Hope this helps.